# symfony 1.4: Invalid culture supplied

Tags: cookies, internationalization, symfony-1.4, culture

Sometimes I get the following exception:

> Invalid culture supplied: %SF_DEFAULT_CULTURE%

When I look into the web debug bar I can see that the culture is set:

```
default_culture: de 
... 
sf_default_culture: de
```

de is my default culture, the i18n files are there.

After clearing the cookies and restarting the browser (IE) the error disappears.

Do you have some ideas what's the problem?

Comment: Hm, I make in settigs.yml:  `i18n:true` and `default_culture:de` and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax for the culture is `country_REGION`, so you could try to set in your `settings.yml`:

```
all:
  .settings:
    default_culture: de_DE
```

Of course you will choose your right region... I saw there are also de_AT, de_BE, de_CH, de_LI and de_LU.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Do I then need to change the i18n folder names, too?
Now I have i18n/de/messages.po.

Comment: I use sfFormLanguage to switch the language, when I try to send de_DE I get an exception the language de_DE does noiot exist.

Comment: I tried this right now, with sfFormLanguage you can't send de_DE.

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce your initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

I now found a setting in apps/frontend/config/factories.yml:

```
default:
  user:
    class: myUser
    param:
      timeout:         1800
      logging:         %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
      use_flash:       true
      default_culture: %SF_DEFAULT_CULTURE%
```

It seems that the system sometimes can't parse the value of %SF_DEFAULT_CULTURE%. So I changed it hard to "de". Hopefully it works.

(It's still funny that symfony 1.4 seems to be inconsistent with the culture handling. On one side it wants a "de_DE" notation but the sfFormLanguage can only handle "de". I now stay with the two-charactar notation.).