# I am trying to learn admin generation in symfony 1.4 with "Jobeet Project",but I am facing Invalid culture supplied: %SF_DEFAULT_CULTURE% error

Tags: symfony-1.4, culture

" I am trying to learn admin generation in symfony 1.4  with "Jobeet Project",but I am facing   Invalid culture supplied: %SF_DEFAULT_CULTURE% error."

Comment: Please, give us more details. Where and when do you get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe here you can get your solution:

[symfony 1.4: Invalid culture supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297328/symfony-1-4-invalid-culture-supplied)

Seems to be the same problem. Revise your `settings.yml` and `factories.yml`

Comment: Hi @Dani, I am very thankful for to take interest in novice programmers to help him/her solved their problems...
Now days I am working with Symfony 2.x.